# Class file opens with notepad and is completely blank after computer restart

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

My friend's GameElements.cs seems to have become corrupted in some way. We're both studying in the same class, and he sent me his project and I can't open the file either. I can't troubleshoot his solution, as he is using XNA and I'm using MonoGame.

Sadly, he does not have any back-ups (this way he'll learn the hard way though) and neither one of us are familiar with neither Visual Studio nor programming at all, as we're just a couple months into the course.

The file is still 12kb, even though I can only select/copy blank spaces. I have no idea if it's possible to restore the code from it, there is obviously data in the file.

This is a link to download the whole solution, though the corrupt file in question is "GameElements.cs". We both would appreciate it greatly if someone was able to recover the code! http://www.filedropper.com/xnabus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below for the code from GameElements.cs. Hope this helps :). You could use any .Net Disassembler to do this. I used ILSpy and decompiled your code from XNA bus.exe file.

Note that, sometimes there could be minor issues with names of classes or methods. So, please go through the code once completely to ensure this.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace XNA_bus
{
    internal static class GameElements
    {
        public enum State
        {
            Menu,
            Levels,
            Level1,
            Level2,
            Level3,
            Run,
            Highscore,
            Quit
        }

        private static Meny meny;

        private static Levels levels;

        private static Player player;

        private static List<Fiender> Fiende;

        private static List<GuldMynt> guldMynt;

        private static List<Powerup> SuperSkepp;

        private static List<Powerup> PenetratingBullets;

        private static Texture2D guldMyntSprite;

        private static Texture2D SuperskeppSprite;

        private static Texture2D PenetratingbulletsSprite;

        private static Utskrifter printText;

        private static Bakgrund bakgrund;

        private static Boss1 boss1;

        private static int boss1Liv = 3;

        private static int playerLiv = 1;

        public static GameElements.State currentState;

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            GameElements.guldMynt = new List<GuldMynt>();
            GameElements.SuperSkepp = new List<Powerup>();
            GameElements.PenetratingBullets = new List<Powerup>();
        }

        public static void LoadContent(ContentManager content, GameWindow window)
        {
            GameElements.player = new Player(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/player/Player"), 0f, 200f, 2.5f, 4.5f, content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/player/bullet"));
            GameElements.bakgrund = new Bakgrund(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/bakgrund"), window);
            GameElements.boss1 = new Boss1(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Enemies/Boss1"), 700f, 360f);
            GameElements.meny = new Meny(0);
            GameElements.meny.AddItem(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Meny/Start"), 1, window);
            GameElements.meny.AddItem(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Meny/Highscore"), 6, window);
            GameElements.meny.AddItem(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Meny/Avsluta"), 7, window);
            GameElements.levels = new Levels(1);
            GameElements.levels.AddItem(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Meny/Level 1"), 2, window);
            GameElements.levels.AddItem(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Meny/Level 2"), 3, window);
            GameElements.levels.AddItem(content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Meny/Level 3"), 4, window);
            GameElements.Fiende = new List<Fiender>();
            Random random = new Random();
            Texture2D tmpsprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Enemies/Predator");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int rndX = random.Next(window.get_ClientBounds().Width / 2, window.get_ClientBounds().Width - tmpsprite.get_Width());
                int rndY = random.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Height - tmpsprite.get_Height());
                Predator temp = new Predator(tmpsprite, (float)rndX, (float)rndY);
                GameElements.Fiende.Add(temp);
            }
            tmpsprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Enemies/mina");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int rndX = random.Next(window.get_ClientBounds().Width / 2, window.get_ClientBounds().Width - tmpsprite.get_Width());
                int rndY = random.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Height - tmpsprite.get_Height());
                Mine temp2 = new Mine(tmpsprite, (float)rndX, (float)rndY);
                GameElements.Fiende.Add(temp2);
            }
            GameElements.printText = new Utskrifter(content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font1"));
            GameElements.guldMyntSprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Powerups/SpelMynt");
            GameElements.SuperskeppSprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Powerups/PowerUp");
            GameElements.PenetratingbulletsSprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Powerups/PowerUp2");
        }

        public static GameElements.State MenyUpdate(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            return (GameElements.State)GameElements.meny.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public static void MenyDraw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            GameElements.bakgrund.Draw(spriteBatch);
            GameElements.meny.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        public static GameElements.State RunUpdate(ContentManager content, GameWindow window, GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GameElements.bakgrund.Update(window);
            GameElements.player.Update(window, gameTime);
            foreach (Fiender f in GameElements.Fiende.ToList<Fiender>())
            {
                foreach (Bullet b in GameElements.player.AntSkott.ToList<Bullet>())
                {
                    if (f.CheckCollision(b))
                    {
                        f.Liv = false;
                        GameElements.player.poäng++;
                        if (!GameElements.player.PenetratingBullets)
                        {
                            GameElements.player.AntSkott.Remove(b);
                        }
                        else if (GameElements.player.PenetratingBullets)
                        {
                            if (gameTime.get_TotalGameTime().TotalSeconds > GameElements.player.PenetratingBulletsTime + 2.0)
                            {
                                GameElements.player.PenetratingBullets = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (f.Liv)
                {
                    if (f.CheckCollision(GameElements.player))
                    {
                        GameElements.playerLiv--;
                        GameElements.player.Liv = false;
                    }
                    f.Update(window);
                }
                else
                {
                    GameElements.Fiende.Remove(f);
                }
                if (!f.FKoll)
                {
                    GameElements.Fiende.Remove(f);
                    GameElements.playerLiv--;
                }
            }
            if (GameElements.boss1.Liv)
            {
                foreach (Bullet b in GameElements.player.AntSkott.ToList<Bullet>())
                {
                    if (GameElements.boss1.CheckCollision(b))
                    {
                        GameElements.player.AntSkott.Remove(b);
                        GameElements.boss1Liv--;
                    }
                }
                GameElements.boss1.Update(window);
            }
            if (GameElements.boss1Liv == 0)
            {
                GameElements.boss1.Liv = false;
            }
            GameElements.State result;
            if (!GameElements.boss1.Liv)
            {
                GameElements.Reset(window, content);
                result = GameElements.State.Menu;
            }
            else
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                int newMynt = random.Next(1, 200);
                if (newMynt == 1)
                {
                    int rndX = random.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Width - GameElements.guldMyntSprite.get_Width());
                    int rndY = random.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Height - GameElements.guldMyntSprite.get_Height());
                    GameElements.guldMynt.Add(new GuldMynt(GameElements.guldMyntSprite, (float)rndX, (float)rndY));
                }
                foreach (GuldMynt gc in GameElements.guldMynt.ToList<GuldMynt>())
                {
                    if (gc.Liv)
                    {
                        gc.Update(gameTime);
                        if (gc.CheckCollision(GameElements.player))
                        {
                            GameElements.guldMynt.Remove(gc);
                            GameElements.player.Poäng++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GameElements.guldMynt.Remove(gc);
                    }
                }
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int newPowerup = rnd.Next(1, 300);
                if (newPowerup == 1)
                {
                    int rndX = rnd.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Width - GameElements.SuperskeppSprite.get_Width());
                    int rndY = rnd.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Height - GameElements.SuperskeppSprite.get_Height());
                    GameElements.SuperSkepp.Add(new Powerup(GameElements.SuperskeppSprite, (float)rndX, (float)rndY));
                }
                foreach (Powerup Power in GameElements.SuperSkepp.ToList<Powerup>())
                {
                    if (Power.Liv)
                    {
                        Power.Update(gameTime);
                        if (Power.CheckCollision(GameElements.player))
                        {
                            GameElements.SuperSkepp.Remove(Power);
                            GameElements.player.SuperSkepp = true;
                            GameElements.player.SuperSkeppTime = gameTime.get_TotalGameTime().TotalSeconds;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GameElements.SuperSkepp.Remove(Power);
                    }
                }
                Random rnd2 = new Random();
                int NewPowerup = rnd2.Next(1, 300);
                if (NewPowerup == 1)
                {
                    int rndX = rnd2.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Width - GameElements.PenetratingbulletsSprite.get_Width());
                    int rndY = rnd2.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Height - GameElements.PenetratingbulletsSprite.get_Height());
                    GameElements.PenetratingBullets.Add(new Powerup(GameElements.PenetratingbulletsSprite, (float)rndX, (float)rndY));
                }
                foreach (Powerup P in GameElements.PenetratingBullets.ToList<Powerup>())
                {
                    if (P.Liv)
                    {
                        P.Update(gameTime);
                        if (P.CheckCollision(GameElements.player))
                        {
                            GameElements.PenetratingBullets.Remove(P);
                            GameElements.player.PenetratingBullets = true;
                            GameElements.player.PenetratingBulletsTime = gameTime.get_TotalGameTime().TotalSeconds;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GameElements.PenetratingBullets.Remove(P);
                    }
                }
                if (!GameElements.player.Liv || GameElements.playerLiv == 0)
                {
                    GameElements.Reset(window, content);
                    result = GameElements.State.Menu;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = GameElements.State.Run;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static void RunDraw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            GameElements.boss1.Draw(spriteBatch);
            GameElements.bakgrund.Draw(spriteBatch);
            GameElements.player.Draw(spriteBatch);
            foreach (Fiender f in GameElements.Fiende)
            {
                f.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            foreach (GuldMynt gc in GameElements.guldMynt)
            {
                gc.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            foreach (Powerup Power in GameElements.SuperSkepp)
            {
                Power.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            foreach (Powerup p in GameElements.PenetratingBullets)
            {
                p.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            GameElements.printText.Print("Points:" + GameElements.player.poäng, spriteBatch, 0, 0);
            GameElements.printText.Print("Boss Liv:" + GameElements.boss1Liv, spriteBatch, 680, 0);
            GameElements.printText.Print("Liv:" + GameElements.playerLiv, spriteBatch, 0, 20);
        }

        public static GameElements.State HighScoreUpdate()
        {
            GameElements.State result;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(27))
            {
                result = GameElements.State.Menu;
            }
            else
            {
                result = GameElements.State.Highscore;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static void HighScoreDraw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
        }

        private static void Reset(GameWindow window, ContentManager content)
        {
            GameElements.boss1Liv = 3;
            GameElements.playerLiv = 1;
            GameElements.boss1.Liv = true;
            GameElements.player.Reset(0f, 200f, 2.5f, 4.5f);
            GameElements.Fiende.Clear();
            Random random = new Random();
            Texture2D tmpsprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Enemies/Predator");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int rndX = random.Next(window.get_ClientBounds().Width / 2, window.get_ClientBounds().Width - tmpsprite.get_Width());
                int rndY = random.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Height - tmpsprite.get_Height());
                Predator temp = new Predator(tmpsprite, (float)rndX, (float)rndY);
                GameElements.Fiende.Add(temp);
            }
            tmpsprite = content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/Enemies/mina");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int rndX = random.Next(window.get_ClientBounds().Width / 2, window.get_ClientBounds().Width - tmpsprite.get_Width());
                int rndY = random.Next(0, window.get_ClientBounds().Height - tmpsprite.get_Height());
                Mine temp2 = new Mine(tmpsprite, (float)rndX, (float)rndY);
                GameElements.Fiende.Add(temp2);
            }
        }

        public static GameElements.State LevelsUpdate(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            return (GameElements.State)GameElements.levels.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public static void LevelsDraw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
        {
            GameElements.bakgrund.Draw(spritebatch);
            GameElements.levels.Draw(spritebatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot on behalf of my friend! I installed the .NET Reflector, but didn't quite understand what it did, I've still got a VERY basic knowledge of mostly everything in programming. Thanks again for the help! :)

Comment: No probs. Best wishes with your project! Please mark this as the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: @Martin I am facing same issue can you please explain a bit more how can i recover my class file?

Comment: @UmangPatwa sorry, I was away for a while and missed this question. If you still have not figured this out, you can install one of the .NET Disassembler to decompile .net assemblies as long as those are not signed ones. You can give ILSpy a try and let me know if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: what if the dll was overwritten with the corrupt file , the dll still compiles with the corrupt file but when disassembly it shows also blank.. this is a terrible Visual studio experience!

Comment: not sure, i have quite understood your question. Are you saying that you have accidentally lost the correct one and just got the corrupted DLL file? If so, what do you mean by saying "DLL still compiles"?